# How To Call A Function From Functional Component In React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-router, react-navigation

Calling a function from Class component is easy. But how to call a function from functional component in another class or functional component?

Any solution for that. I searched lot of tutorial on stackOverflow but still there is no solution. Please provide any solution.

**DrawerSetting.dart**

```
        import * as React from 'react';
    import { Button, View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
    import {
      createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView,
      DrawerItemList,
      DrawerItem,
    } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import Resources from '../DrawerScreens/Resources';
    import Themes from '../DrawerScreens/Themes';
    import AboutUs from '../DrawerScreens/AboutUs';
    import CustomSidebarMenu from './CustomSidebarMenu';
    import Login from '../Validation/Login';
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

    export default function DrawerSetting({route, navigation }) {

    console.log("email is = " + password);

      add = () =>{
        console.log("Addition called");
      }


      AsyncStorage.getItem("userId").then((val) => {
        console.log("Drawer valuse are=" + val);
      });
        

      return (
        <NavigationContainer independent={true} >
          <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Resources" drawerContent={(props) => <CustomSidebarMenu {...props} />}

          >
            <Drawer.Screen name="Resources" component={Resources}
              options={{ drawerLabelStyle: { fontSize: 16, color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold', } }}
            />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Themes" component={Themes}
              options={{ drawerLabelStyle: { fontSize: 16, color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold', } }}
            />
            <Drawer.Screen name="About Us" component={AboutUs}
              options={{ drawerLabelStyle: { fontSize: 16, color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold', } }}
            />


          </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
```

How to call the -> add() function from the DrawerSetting() component in another class or functional component?

Comment: Hi, can your share some more details, what you trying yo archive?

Comment: You can obviously pass the function as prop to the other component. If, this is not the answer you are looking for, you have to add some more details to the question

Comment: I edited please see